# Получение отрисованного шаблона

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-3

Каким образом можно из стандартного контроллера Zend3 вернуть «отрендеренный» `ViewModel()` шаблон для асинхронной передачи передачи (`text/html`)

Comment: поясните, куда, что хотите вернуть, что-то непонятен ваш вопрос

Comment: У меня не получается корректно запустить PhpRenderer по документации, Unable to render template...

Comment: покажите ваш module.config.php, там обычно настройки view. под ключем view_manager

Comment: view manager практически не изменился с момента установки, стандартная отрисовка через ViewModel работает без нареканий

Comment: покажите код, что есть, что не работает, мне не очень понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать

Comment: $renderer = new PhpRenderer();

$model = new ViewModel();
$model->setTemplate('application/index/index');
return /*echo*/ $renderer->render($model);

Comment: а зачем вам так делать? ZF по умолчанию уже всё это делает, что бы то что вы хотите работала, делайте как в докуменатации, https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.renderer.php-renderer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, делать что-то типо этого, но так делать не надо.
PhpRenderer используется по умолчанию

```
public function debugAction()
{
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $renderer = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
    $resolver = new \Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver();
    $renderer->setResolver($resolver);

    $map = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver(array(
        'email/test' => __DIR__ . '/../../view/email/test.phtml',
    ));
    $stack = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack(array(
        'script_paths' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../../view',
        )
    ));

    $resolver->attach($map)->attach($stack);
    $viewModel->setTemplate('email/test');
    echo $renderer->render($viewModel);
    exit;
    // return $viewModel;
}
```

Comment: Да, работает с die/exit, хотя, конечно, вряд ли это изначально предусматриваемый вариант решения